# Can I get MSVC to be less strict about "C4127: conditional expression is constant"

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2019, compiler-warnings, c4127

I'm using MSVC 16 2019 with many warnings turned on, including C4127: conditional expression is constant. However, I have code which looks like:

```
template <bool B>
void foo(int x) {
    if (B && x == 0) { do_stuff(); }
    do_other_stuff();
}
```

... and the warning is triggered when B is false.

I want to keep this error in general, but I don't want it to warn gratuitously when the constness of the condition expression is only due to template instantiation.

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573996/c4127-conditional-expression-is-constant) is related, but - the code is not going to (significantly) change, so that's not what I'm asking. Not in C++17 either.

Comment: You can use a `#pragma` to turn off individual warnings and restore them again after the offending block of code.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Make that an answer?

Comment: Use `if constexpr (B) if (x == 0) { do_stuff(); }`

Comment: @273K: Yes, that would work with C++17 (which I can't use).

Comment: @einpoklum If you are only using MSVC, it doesn't support C++11 and supports `if constexpr` as an extension in C++14 mode. It also prevents the compiler error if you just have `if (B) if (x == 0) { do_stuff(); }` (without if constexpr: https://godbolt.org/z/Wbo767sEK )

Comment: @Artyer: I actually never use MSVC myself, but some of my library's users do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reformat the function to

```
template <bool B>
void foo(int x) {
    // Doing this to remove B triggering a constant condition warning when B is false
    // future: replace with if constexpr in C++17+
    bool b = B;
    if (b && x == 0) { do_stuff(); }
    do_other_stuff();
}
```

and now `b` is not a constant expression so the warning should not apply anymore.

Comment: @ThomasWeller And that is why code comments are important.  OP says they can't use C++17 so `if constexpr` wont help yet.

Comment: (sigh) I can do that, but I'd still feel like a fool led by the nose by the compiler.

Comment: @einpoklum: this will not be the only time. Compilers could be so much smarter, especially with templates. I guess we have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily disable the warning for that code block, with a #pragma directive, as Mark Ransom suggests too.

```
template <bool B>
void foo(int x) {
#pragma warning(disable:4127)
    if (B && x == 0) { do_stuff(); }
#pragma warning(default:4127)
    do_other_stuff();
}
```

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-170

Comment: Rather that the #pragma warning(disable, )/#pragma warning(default, ), I suggest that you use #pragma warning(suppress, ) if there is only one line in a given function that is going to trigger the warning. Suppress turns off the warning for just the next line.